# Regular Expression Validation (Regex) fixed emailaddresses before the @

Tags: regex

I understand that the regular (Regex) to validate emailaddresses is:

```
[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}
```

However is there a way to force an user to fill in only one of the following:

```
admin@example.com
administrator@example.com
hostmaster@example.com
webmaster@example.com
postmaster@example.com
```

So they are force to use admin, administrator, etc. in conjunction with their own domain?

I will be using this to validate SSL certificates. Apparently people just fill in nonsense even though it's clearly explained on the website.

Thank you.

Comment: use (admin|administrator|hostmaster|webmaster|postmaster)@[A-Z]...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do it with a silly regex like:

```
/^(?:admin|administrator|webmaster)@.../
```

However, this set of titles is something that you might want to modify and probably shouldn't be directly embedded in low-level code.  A two-step approach would be better.

First capture the first part of the email address with an appropriate regex.  For example, your regex as above but with a capture group:

```
/^([A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+)@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/
```

Then check to see whether this first part appears in a list of allowed words.

*Note: I am sidestepping the issue here of whether your original regex is appropriate.  It doesn't fully match all allowed email addresses, but that may not be all that important in your context.*

Comment: Sorry dan1111, I misunderstood. :|